# Image is not displaying although saving in DB and folder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Image is not displaying however it is saving in db and folder.

I could not get it where is the problem

**apperance.blade.php**

```php
<div id="bgimage" class="hovercover text-center">
    <img class="img-responsive"  src="img/{{$image->image ?? ''}}" style="margin-top: {{$image->position ?? ''}}">

    <div class="hover-div">
        <form id="hoverform" action="{{url('/employee-appearance')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <label class="custom-file-upload" title="Change Cover Image" for="file-upload"> <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> Change Cover </label>
            <input id="file-upload" name="file" type="file">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="adjimage" class="hovercover1 text-center" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

**imageProcessController**

```php
public function upload()
{
    $image=DB::table('images')->latest('image','position')->first(); 
    return view('user.employeeforms.appearance',compact('image')) ;
}

public function postupload(Request $request)
{
    $file         = $request->file('file'); 
    $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,jpg');  
    $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

    if($validator->passes()) { 
        $image = $file->move( 'img', sprintf('%s-%s.%s', time(), "abc", explode('/', $file->getMimeType())[1]));
        $img            = new Image; 
        $img->image     = $image->getFilename();
        $img->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be possibilities that it could be.
But the most likely one is that the symlink has not been set yet!?

`php artisan storage:link`

If you have already set it, look in the storage/app order where the files are. If they are under storage/app/img then you have to change the link like this:

`<img src="img/{{$image->image ?? ''}}"`

should be:

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/img/' . $image->image ?? "placeholder.jpg" ) }}">`

Comment: its not working for me,images are stored in img folder

Comment: @sanarana ok. you recieve a error message? you checked in the browser console or put the `http://127.0.0.1:80xx/storage/img/your-image-name.jpg` in your brwoser. what html status code you get?

Comment: @sanarana Your image model have the created_at field? it is necessary if you use latest()